# Join Performance Issue in Oracle

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, database-performance

We have are having 2 tables.

1. Table -  XYZ - > Having over 189 M Records
2. Table - ABC - > Having only 1098 records.

Our join query is some what like

```
select a.a, a.b, a.c 
from xyz a , ABC r 
where a.d = r.d
    and a.sub not like '0%' 
    and ((a.eff_dat < sysdate) or (a.eff_date is null))
```

This is how our query is performing. In any way can it be optmised to perform faster.
Apart from the not like, can you suggest me any other method.

In the explain plan I have seen that it is taking the 189 M as itrator and checking with the 1098 records which is taking more time.
I swapped the tables after the from Key word but also it did not work.
Tried leading hint, which also not servered the purpose.
Also a.d column is an indexed one which is also used in the hint.

Please do suggest any methods for optimisation.

Comment: Can you post the explain plan the actual explain plan and every index that these columns are in in please?

Comment: how many rows do you expect to be returned from your query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have multiple predicates on a table such as:

```
    a.sub not like '0%' 
and ((a.eff_dat < sysdate) or (a.eff_date is null))
```

... it is rather unlikely that the optimiser will accurately estimate the cardinality of the result set unless you use dynamic sampling, so check the explain plan to see whether:

1. Dynamic sampling is being invoked.
2. The estimation of the cardinalities are correct.

If the predicates are not very selective -- if they do not eliminate something in the order of 90% or the rows in the table -- then it is unlikely that an index will be of help in finding the rows, and a full scan (with partition pruning if the table is partitioned in a way that supports that) is likely to be the best access path.

I'd be reasonably sure that if there is a foreign key between the tables (ie. that all values of a.d exist in r.d) then the best access path is going to be a full scan of XYZ with a hash join to ABC.
By the way, you mention hints but do not include them in the question. It's also unhelpful to hide the purpose of the tables with fake names, as the names often give valuable clues about the type of data and distribution of values within the data sets.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem most of the cost would be in the (presumed) full table scan on the large table. I would suggest rewriting your WHERE condition as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ A
WHERE SUBSTR(A.SUB, 1, 1) <> '0'
AND NVL(A.EFF_DAT, TO_DATE('01-01-0001', 'MM-DD-YYYY')) < SYSDATE ;
```

And then create a function index that includes all the relevant columns:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_XYZ1 ON
XYZ(NVL(EFF_DAT, TO_DATE('01-01-0001', 'MM-DD-YYYY')), SUB, D);
```

Make sure the new index is being picked up by the cost-based optimizer, by checking the execution plan.

LIKE, NOT LIKE and the OR operand are some of the worst things you can use in a WHERE condition.

Comment: You'd only want to create and promote the use of an index where the use of that index is lower cost than a table scan, of course. I'd also suggest that you try indexing on (EFF_DAT,0) as well/instead, as you're likely to get a smaller index that includes null eff_dat's automatically without using a magic date.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by (EFF_DAT, 0). You can't do NVL(EFF_DAT, 0). If you simply index on EFF_DAT, the CBO won't use it because the query uses it wrapped in a function.

Comment: "CREATE INDEX IX_XYZ1 ON XYZ(EFF_DAT, 0)", thus creating a composite index on the column EFF_DAT and the numeric literal "0". Because "0" is known by the optimiser to never be null, it knows that all values of EFF_DAT are included in the index and thus EFF_DAT IS NULL can be answered from the index.

Comment: I tried that but the CBO is choosing not to use it. 

`CREATE INDEX IX_XYZ1 ON
 XYZ(NVL(EFF_DAT, TO_DATE('01-01-0001', 'MM-DD-YYYY')), SUB, D);
CREATE INDEX IX_XYZ2 ON XYZ(EFF_DAT, 0);
EXEC DBMS_STATS.SET_TABLE_STATS( ownname => '<my schema>', tabname => 'XYZ', NUMROWS => '190000000');
`

Comment: It would depend on the data distribution and the query as well, but could be a moot point for the OP due to his/her data distribution.